# CSS Transform Transition not working properly (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

**Note:** This question requests an explanation of CSS transform output on Chrome.

---

### Description

- I made a rhombus using css `skew` and `rotate` transforms.
- I added `:hover` pseudo-class to that element and changed its skew angle.

The expected result was that on hovering the rhombus, the angle of the rhombus will change.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y41qxqz2/) and 
**snippet :**

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 140px;
    left: 120px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
    background: red;
    transition: 0.8s linear all;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-30deg, -30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-30deg, -30deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-30deg, -30deg);
    transition: 0.8s linear all;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Problem

This is working fine on **Firefox v35.0.1** and **IE v10**. See the output below :

[image: ff&ie]

But on **Chrome 40.0.2214.115**, the output seems to be different. The angle of the rhombus changes, but not evenly. And near the end of transition of transform property, the rhombus "step-ends" to the desired output, instead of transforming transitionally.
Its neither working with `skewX(Xdeg) skewY(Ydeg)` nor `skew(Xdeg, Ydeg)` : **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jqu3zun/)**.

The **GC** output is below :

[image]

**Question :**  Chrome seems to support the deprecated `skew(Xdeg, Ydeg)` but the output with transition is buggy. * What is causing this strange output with chrome?**

**Note:** This effect is achievable using `scaleX` transform too, but this is a deliberately made question.

Comment: it looks like rotation transformation takes place later than skew (as it is being recalculated)..

Comment: this can be a workaround http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/y41qxqz2/7/

Comment: Adding to @web-tiki's answer (nice) - I'd add positioning to prevent unnecessary overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/y41qxqz2/9/

Comment: Still no answer? This bug is really interesting...

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `clip-path: polygon()` to achieve the same effect. Not yet supported in all browsers unfortunately.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 280px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 20%, 100% 50%, 50% 80%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 80% 50%, 50% 100%, 20% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

/* center */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Although i asked explanation too, but this is working nicely in chrome!

Answer (score -2):

I have been working with transitions now on chrome. I find using position tags like this.

```css
div:hover {
    position:relative; /*Desribes the type of position*/
    left:40; /*X Coordinate*/
    top:25; /*Y Coordinate*/
}
```

Make the transitions work on chrome.

Here are some resources
-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions
-http://blog.wercker.com/2013/10/02/Chrome-css-animation.html

Hope it helped :)